# What exactly is a ‘cambay’?

Tags: translation, terminology

I am editing a text in English that doesn’t really have anything to do with Japan, but with India. In it, there is a letter from 1798 (translated from the original Danish) which contains the following:

> The bearer of this [letter] is Madam Gauttier, the widow of a French Lieutenant Colonel Gauttier, a man whom I held in the greatest esteem. My dear Brother has formerly known her as Madam Clausman. The lady has shown the goodness to bring to my dear Brother **a Japanese mandarin’s cambay, which is the winter gown of a distinguished Japanese**. I have been promised the undergarment for this dress and will send it as soon as I get it. It deserves to be preserved because of its rarity.

I’ve never heard of anything that may be termed a *cambay* before, so naturally I took to Google—with dismal results.

Cambay is of course the name of an erstwhile [Indian state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambay_State), indeed one that had a thriving textile sector, but the letter specifically says that a cambay is a Japanese type of garment, so textile from Cambay in India doesn’t seem to be what is referred to here.

Sadly, I can find absolutely no hints or references to any kind of Japanese garment called any variation of *cambay* that I can come up with (*cambey*, *kambai*, *kanbai*, *kambei*, *cambi*, etc.—the last one is apparently a fashion designer), so I’m no further.

A rather wild guess on my part is that the first part of *cambay* may be 寒{かん}, since it is described as being a **winter** gown (and if *cambay* is some ad-hoc transliteration of a Japanese word, it does look like *onyomi*). Or perhaps, if it is important that it is specifically a mandarin’s garment, 官{かん}.

But what is *bay*, then? Some old word for ‘clothes’? Perhaps something like 被{ひ} or 披{ひ} ‘cover’ (in somewhat bizarre transliteration)?

In short: **what is a *cambay*?** Is it any kind of Japanese anything, or was the writer of the letter (who was, after all, a Dane stationed in India, and probably knew little or nothing about Japan) simply mistaken?

Comment: I'd like to see what the original Danish said, as "cambay" appears here to be either an existing English word unknown to us now, or a transliteration of a transliteration.

Comment: @JAF So would I, actually. I wonder why I hadn’t considered that before. I just ordered the original material from the archives, so perhaps I’ll find it’s been misquoted or reads otherwise in the original Danish.

Comment: Could it be related to *kambase* = face, visage; honour? The *Vocabvlario da Lingoa de Iapam* (1603) has this entry: *Faigan. Cambaxeuo vogamu. i, võmeni cacaru.* (拝顔：かんばせを拝む。i, お目にかかる。)  glossed as *Venerar vendo pessoa nobre.* ("To treat with respect when seeing a nobleperson"). It has an extra せ (then pronounced [ɕe]), and it's not really about clothing; but the first part sounds like *cambay*, and it has to do with nobleperson's external looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your original question summary:

> In short: **what is a *cambay*?** Is it any kind of Japanese anything, or was the writer of the letter (who was, after all, a Dane stationed in India, and probably knew little or nothing about Japan) simply mistaken?

- A "cambay" is a kimono.
- The term does indeed come from the name of an Indian place where textiles were a major industry.

Digging around, I stumbled across an explanation in Google Books, in the 2018 title [*Fashion, Identity, and Power in Modern Asia*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ivZ0DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA311&ots=frIn5khoEA&dq=japanese%20cambay&pg=PA311#v=onepage&q=cambay&f=false).  That link should take you right to the relevant page 311, with this text (emphasis mine):

> In the fifteenth and sixteenth centuries, **the kimono, taken to Europe by the Dutch, became a favored garment of the new elites** and these robes were made with Indian textiles in the Western Indian port of Khambhat or Cambay.  **Variously called "the Japan", Cambay robe,** or banyan (a word originally used in the mid-fifteenth century to designate all Hindu traders and brokers, that is men of substance), it became a marker of status and distinction, and **India became the source of the Japanese robe.**

---

Please post if the above does not address your question and I can edit to update.

Comment: Well, the book in question has been out for nearly three years now, so there’s no question of this making it into the book – but it is nice to finally have some corroboration that a cambay is (or was) a thing!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it may refer to [合羽 (かっぱ; kappa)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%88%E7%BE%BD)?

It was originally a loanword borrowed from *capa* (="cape") in Portuguese. According to Wikipedia and [this article](http://www.ishinotent.co.jp/Kappa/kappa.html), *kappa* in those days was actually considered as a status symbol for rich people. They say that many people wore so gorgeous *kappa* to show them off that the government had to prohibit wearing *kappa*. Try Google Image Search with `江戸時代 合羽`.

Today, [かっぱ](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%90%88%E7%BE%BD) is just a mundane and old-fashioned word for (レイン)コート.

Comment: That could be. The _-mb-_ doesn’t seem like a likely transcription/transliteration outcome of _p_, but they often get things royally screwed up, so it’s hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes up my mind is 甚平(じんべい; jinbei).

It is a traditional inexpensive clothing for summer but not for winter and the kanji 甚 doesn't sound *kan* or *cam* anyway. But its radical is 甘(*kan*) and also, as a reminder, there are some kanji, which sounds *kan* and are partly composed of 甚, such as 堪 and 勘.

If you only focus on a Japanese gown during winter, I suggest 褞袍(どてら; dotera), which is also known as 丹前(たんぜん; tanzen).